# the object behind is visible

Tags: text-object, layers, visibility

While editing, the text is behind the curtain. but during rendering (picture 3) the text appears in front.[image]

Comment: It would’ve been far better to have the screenshots separate. The way stackexchange works, you can put them in line with your text (IE they don’t all appear at the end of the question). As it is, I think you actually did extra work for you that made it more confusing.

Comment: I couldn't manage to add the pictures separately :D so I combined 3 pictures in blender :D

Comment: I don’t know how you could manage to not be able to add the three pictures separately. The embed tool is very straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're dealing with a Grease Pencil stroke - not a text object.

The usual culprit in this case is under the *Properties -> View Layer -> Passes -> Data* section. Check that the *Z* data pass is turned on.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem is solved.

Comment: @muffinman No problem! Could you accept the solution?